# Lagrangian cobordisms from a Legendrian knot to its scaled version

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology, contact-geometry, contact-topology

Having a Legendrian knot L in $\mathbb R^3$ and its scale aL (the length of Reeb chords of it are scaled by a>0), are these two Legendrians Legendrian isotopic? Maybe weaker, is there an exact Lagrangian concordance from L to aL?

Comment: When you say "scale $aL$", do you mean the knot that is stretched in the $z$-direction by a factor of $a$? (So if you have a parametrisation $(x(t), y(t), z(t))$ of $L$ then $aL$ is parametrised by $(x(t), y(t), az(t))$? I'm assuming that we're looking at $dz - ydx$ as a contact form.)

Comment: What I mean is taking an image of a knot  that corresponds to the image of a diffeomorphism that sends z to az,  x to ax and y to y/a.

Comment: Then isn't $t \mapsto tL$ a Legendrian isotopy?